# Python - exclude data with double quotes and parenthesis

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list which contains set of words in single quotes and double quotes, now i want to grep all the data only in single quotes.

```
Input_
sentence = ['(telco_name_list.event_date','reference.date)',"'testwebsite.com'",'data_flow.code',"'/long/page/data.jsp'"]
```

Output:

```
telco_name_list.event_date,reference.date,data_flow.code
```

I want to exclude the parenthesis and string in double quotes.

Comment: can't be done.  the quotes are just part of the syntax, the string objects themselves do not have quotes.

Comment: Is the input_sentence in python code, or is it a text file you are reading (whether that text file is also python code doesn't matter at that point)? If the former, you really can't do anything to "parse" that, to my knowledge. If you are instead parsing a string from a file, you have options. We need to know which it is, to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the data source is from text file, in which it looks like (telco_name_list.event_date,reference.date),'testwebsite.com','data_flow.code','/long/page/data.jsp']

Comment: Corrected data from file (telco_name_list.event_date,reference.date),'testwebsite.com',data_flow.code,'/long/page/data.jsp']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged the post as `python-3.x`, I'm assuming you want to write python code. Based on your example this would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
Input_sentence = ['(telco_name_list.event_date','reference.date)',"'testwebsite.com'",'data_flow.code',"'/long/page/data.jsp'"]

comma = False
result = []
for i in range(len(Input_sentence)):
  e = Input_sentence[i]
  if e.startswith("'"): continue
  e = e.replace('(', '').replace(')', '') 
  if comma:
    print(",", end="")
  comma = True
  print(e, end="")
print()
```

This code iterates through the list, ignoring elements which begin with a single quote and filtering out parentheses from elements before printing them on stdout. This code works for the given example, but may or may not be what you need as the exact semantics of what you want out are somewhat ambiguous (i.e. is it fine to filter out all parentheses or just the ones at the beginning and end of your elements?).